# Enumerate controls added to panel in a user control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

Using VB.NET (VS 2012) WinForms.

I've created a user control which contains a few labels, buttons etc.  Multiple instances of this user control have been added to a form (user control and form are in the same project).  I applied the following attribute to the user control class to allow it to act as a container at design time, as I add additional controls to each instance of the user control.

```
<Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner,System.Design", GetType(IDesigner))>
```

That seems to work fine.

In some instances of the user control, I am adding a panel, then adding controls into that panel.  What I then want to do from within the user control code, is enumerate all the controls in the panel for the current instance.  I can successfully enumerate the usercontrol.control collection, but I can't see any controls in the panel.controls collection for the panel added at design time to the user control instance.

Any ideas how I can enumerate the panel's controls?

Comment: Are you not able to access the panel by it's name - `usercontrol1.panel1.Controls` ?

Comment: Not really.  From my form I can enumerate `usercontro1.panel1.controls` successfully.  However I need to enumerate them from within the usercontrol code i.e. `me.panel1.control`.

Comment: However, I think I've worked it out.  It actually does work as it should - i.e. from within user control code, `me.panel1.controls` does correctly enumerate the controls.  I was running my enumeration code during form load or in a place before the panel1.controls were actually added to the form.  Oops.  All good when I run it later on.  Thanks for the response DonA.